# Singular or Plural verb with or?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which is correct: a name or number ***was/were*** nowhere to be found.

Comment: I think this might be to do with whether "a name or number" is considered plural or not.

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

*A name or number **was** nowhere to be found.* Both *name* and *number* are singular nouns, so *was* is correct.

> The rule is that **when the subjects are joined by “or” or
>   “neither/nor,” the verb agrees with the subject that is closest to the
>   verb**:

1. *The piano or the book case **has** to go.* BUT *The piano or the tables **have** to go.*
2. *Neither the pillows nor the curtains **match** the couch.* BUT *Neither the pillows nor the blanket **looks** good in this room.*

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Subjects-with-And-and-Or-and-Verb-Agreement supports this, even though it highlights that there is no standardization of this rule and therefore some people don't follow it.